# GNU screen tab gets renamed whenever I type a command

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, window-title

When I use gnu screen, in other tabs, I ssh into other machines, rename the tab accordingly, and do work normally. The tab name sticks.

In a fresh tab, which is just a terminal on the original machine, whenever I type any command, the tab gets renamed to the current working directory.

Example:

/////////// here's how everything looks beforehand

```
    [me@mac ~]$
    [ me ][0*$ me@mac:~  1-$ web01  2$ dev03
```

////////// setting the tab name

```
    [me@mac ~]$ 
    Set window's title to: test
    [ me ][0*$ test  1-$ web01 clone  2$ dev03 clone
```

//////// typing a command: `pwd`

```
    [me@mac ~]$ pwd
    /home/me
    [me@mac ~]$
    [ me ][0*$ me@mac:~  1-$ web01 clone  2$ dev03 clone
```

and the tab is renamed back to the current working dir. This doesn't happen in any tab where I'm ssh'd into another machine. So I thought this might be an issue of my personal settings, but there doesn't seem to be anything in my .bashrc, .bash_profile or .screenrc files that has to do with titles.

Comment: You have an escape sequence in your prompt that sets the window title.

Comment: Nope, looks like that isn't the case: 

        [alison@mac etc]$ echo $PS1

        [\u@\h \W]$

Comment: You can't see escape sequences with `echo`. Look at the statement in your startup file that sets `PS1`.

Comment: It seems to be set in /etc/bashrc (not in /etc/profile), but again I don't see an escape char (\e)...

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '

Comment: Check `$PROMPT_COMMAND` as well. See http://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory

Comment: Ah, I found it, in /etc/profile.d/prompt.sh:

      export PS1="\[\e[31;1m\]\u@${host}\[\e[m\]\w> "

thanks for the help! (why comment instead of answer?)

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused. I changed PS1 to equal something without an escape character in it, and screen still exhibits this behavior....

Comment: I commented because without knowing what's causing it, I can't answer how to fix it.

Comment: Did you logout and log back in after changing the script? `screen inherited the setting from your login shell.

Answer (score 3):

Your shell configuration is setting the terminal title to the command that's currently running. It's a fairly common configuration. Since it's done by the shell, it isn't done if the shell is running on another machine with a different shell configuration. The escape sequence to set the Screen window title is `␛kTITLE␛\` where `␛` is the escape character (byte value 27).

In bash, look for code that emits this escape sequence. The escape character is probably represented as `\e` or `\033`. The code could be in the prompt (`PS1`) or in the command that's executed before displaying a new prompt after running a command (`PROMPT_COMMAND`). Check their values (taking care not to emit the escape sequences to the terminal in case they contain a literal escape character):

```
printf 'PS1=%s\nPROMPT_COMMAND=%s\n' "$PS1" "$PROMPT_COMMAND" | cat -v
```

It's also possible but less common to emit this escape sequence before running a command, via the `DEBUG` trap:

```
trap -p DEBUG
```

These variables (or the trap) would have to be set in the bash configuration, either yours or system-wide: normally `~/.bashrc`, and `/etc/bash.bashrc` on some systems, but also possibly `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_login`, or a file included by one of these. You can narrow it down by running a new shell with fewer settings:

```
env -i bash                  # no environment variables or per-user settings
env -i HOME="$HOME" bash     # no environment variables, normal interactive shell
env -i HOME="$HOME" bash -l  # no environment variables, login shell
HOME=/none bash              # skips your per-user settings
```

A comparison on which of those exhibits the problem will tell you whether the settings come from your settngs or system-wide ones, and whether they're from `.bashrc` (read by interactive shells) or from a login-time file (`.profile`, etc.).

Comment: +1. Instead of that `printf`, I prefer something like `set | grep -E '^(PS[1-4]|PROMPT_COMMAND)='`

Answer (score 2):

PROMPT_COMMAND is getting set in /etc/bashrc:

```
if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
  case $TERM in
  .
  .
  .
    ;;
  screen*)
    if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
    else
        PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
    fi
    ;;
```

So you just need to set PROMPT_COMMAND to '' in your ~/.bashrc to get it to stop updating the tab name, e.g.

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=''
```

or you can just unset it when you have a window name you want to keep:

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

then change the window name with CTRL-a A